# Group Type is set to empty while updating Group

Tags: groups

On ManageGroup page, if group description is updated or if I enable/disable group, the value of GroupType gets updated to an empty value. Ideally, GroupType value must not be updated, it should retain its original value.

Comment: did you manage to reproduce on the demo site?

Comment: and what version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I checked on demo sites. Demo on Drupal and Wordpress also has this bug. Problem is related to 4.7 since it worked on Joomla demo which has v4.6. I am using version 4.7

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a question, it's a bug report ;)

For bug reports, could you use jira, ideally with a patch to fix the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, Xavier, https://civicrm.org/bug-reporting states that we should first post a problem here. I was following that convention :)

Comment: the suggested process is to ask here first if the behaviour your see is expected or if someone else experience it. ie. when you have a question. what you posted is a statement, not a question ;)

Comment: I created the issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18194. Thanks for input :)